# android chat bubble with reply UI

Tags: android, android-layout, chat

I'm trying to create a chat bubble with the following code,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/chat_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:layout_marginStart="64dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:background="@drawable/my_text_bg"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/replyUI"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/reply_ui_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/reply_ui_margin"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/reply_ui_margin"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/reply_ui_minus_margin"
            android:background="@drawable/reply_box_bg_sent"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:elevation="@dimen/reply_ui_elevation"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="@dimen/reply_ui_padding"
            android:visibility="gone">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/replyToName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:textColor="?replyTitleSentColor"
                android:textSize="@dimen/chat_reply_to_text_size" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/replyToTxt"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:textColor="?replyTxtColor"
                android:textSize="@dimen/chat_reply_to_text_size" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sentTxt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/chat_text_margin_start"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/chat_text_margin"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/chat_text_margin"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/chat_text_margin"
            android:autoLink="all"
            android:textColor="?chatTxtColor"
            android:textColorLink="?attr/chatLinkColorSent"
            android:textSize="@dimen/chat_text_size" />


    </LinearLayout>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timeStamp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/chat_timestamp_text_margin"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/chat_timestamp_text_margin"
        android:drawablePadding="@dimen/chat_timestamp_drawable_padding"
        android:textColor="@color/grey"
        android:textSize="@dimen/chat_timestamp_text_size" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And it produces the following output,
[image: chat bubble]
As you can see, the `replyUI` is not filling the entire width of the chat bubble.

So, I tried setting `replyUI` width to `match_parent`, it fills the parent and the output looks like this,
[image: chat bubble 2]

But now I have another problem, If the `sentTxt` text is too short it shrinks the whole layout and `replyUI` is not readable at all. See below image.[image: chat bubble 3]

How can I get the `replyUI` to fill the entire bubble width without shrinking when `sentTxt` is too short? I tried to set a `minWidth` property, but that didn’t work. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be better for you to use `ConstraintLayout` in this case.

You want the `replyUI` width to always match the constraint making it go until to the end of `chat_parent` but at the same time you want its minimum width constrained to its own content width.

`chat_parent` width needs to be `wrap_content`, it will have the width decided by either `replyUI` (if `replyToTxt` is longer than the `sentTxt`) or `sentTxt` (if `sentTxt` is longer than `replyToTxt`)

**Using `app:layout_constraintWidth_min="wrap"` in `replyUI` is the key to achieving the desired effect**

I've played around a little bit changing the dimension, drawables and color values of your snippet just to give you an example. You would probably need to tweak some values (like *gravity, maxLines, maxWidth and constraints margins*)

**Short Reply vs Long Sent Text**

[image: Short Reply vs Long Sent Text]

**Long Reply vs Short Sent Text**
[image: Long Reply Short Sent Text]

Here is the **.xml** for these

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/black">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/chat_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:background="@color/purple_500"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/replyUI"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
            android:background="@color/purple_200"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:maxWidth="160dp"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_min="wrap">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/replyToName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:textColor="@color/purple_500"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                tools:text="You" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/replyToTxt"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                android:maxWidth="160dp"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="13sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/replyToName"
                tools:text="This is a long text" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sentTxt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:autoLink="all"
            android:maxWidth="160dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textColorLink="@color/purple_500"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/replyUI"
            tools:text="Hi" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timeStamp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:drawablePadding="4dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/chat_parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/chat_parent"
        tools:text="13:45" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. How can we set ```sentTxt``` to use 80% of the screen width for ```maxWidth``` attribute instead of hard coding ```android:maxWidth="160dp"```?

Comment: I'm not sure from the top of my head but maybe if you create a guideline view in the outermost `ConstraintLayout`, make `chat_parent` start constrained to it using `app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"`, this will make its width respect `wrap_content` but respect its constraints for a max value... not entirely sure nothing will break but it's worth a try.

Do that also removing the hardcoded maxWidths from the texts.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the text length with code and see if it's too short, set a fixed height for your layout with code, or else set the height to match_parent.

```
LinearLayout view = findViewById(R.id.replyUI);
int size = replyToTxt.getText().toString().length();
if (size < 14) 
{
LayoutParams layoutParams = view.getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.width = newWidth;
view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
}
else {
LayoutParams layoutParams = view.getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.width = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
}
```

Comment: That doesn’t work as ```replyToTxt``` and ```sentTxt``` have different text sizes. What I'm looking for is an XML fix.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `android:minWidth=""` in replyUI linear layout, it will keep min width in case of short test, make sure to use dimens for differnt device support.

Comment: It won't work. I have already mentioned this in the question.